# Am I allowed to use the rss feed of Stackoverflow for one of my iphone application?

Tags: support, feed

I want to use the rss feed of stackoverflow for my iPhone application. Is there any procedure for that?

Comment: Do you want to *read* it on your iPhone or do you want to *use* it in the application you're writing?

Comment: i want to use the existing rss feed in my application

Comment: You're welcome to do this, but may find it easier to use the [official API](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/usage). You can find examples of existing programs that use the API, as well as ask questions about it, over on [stackapps](http://stackapps.com). There's even some existing wrappers for it, which may make your life easier.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about allowed or not, but I would think it's discourage. Much better for everyone (yourself included) if you [use the API](https://stackapps.com/about).